# Can I manually select a .ssh default folder on windows?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, version-control, ssh-keys

So, I followed this to configure my SSH -[Setting up SSH keys for Bitbucket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812519/setting-up-ssh-keys-for-bitbucket-on-windows)- and it works as expected.

For a reason out of knowledge, control and understanding.... The `%HOMEDRIVE%` on my computer is set to Q (a network drive), resulting on GIT storing and looking for my ssh keys on `Q:\Users\MyUser\.ssh`.

I can tell git to create the keys on `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh` (or just copy them from Q to C). But when I want to do a `git pull`, git looks for my keys on Q instead of C, and obviously fails to connect.

Any idea on how to tell git to always look for SSH keys and configurations on a specific folder?

Thanks,
R.

p.d. My `%HOMEPATH%` is propperly configured... if i could at least tell git to use the `%HOMEPATH%` instead of `%HOMEDRIVE%`... that could probably be a fix too.

**--UPDATE--**

I created a `config` file, that redirects ssh.exe from Q to C

```
Host MyHost
    HostName MyIP
    Port MyPort
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile /C/Users/MyUser/.ssh/known_hosts
    IdentityFile /C/Users/MyUser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

So, being able to specify a location for the config file would also help.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try creating a symbolic link/junction from `C:\Users\MyUser\.ssh` to `Q:\Users\MyUser\.ssh`.

Comment: Ok, I tried with `ln` and `mklink`, didn't work (neither with soft link or hard link), maybe because Q is a network drive

Answer (score 1):

So far I solved my issue (in a way i don't really like)... But my solution doesn't answer my question.

I added a variable to my user variables called `HOME` and set it to `C:\Users\MyUser`.
Basically what [rolyat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5503872/rolyat) suggested in this thread [change-the-default-location-for-git-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671461/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-for-git-bash-on-windows)

I don't know the reason why my organization configures `%HOMEDRIVE%` to Q and I don't know if my variable will later affect me accessing network resources or receiving windows updates from my organization...

At least this way i am not dependent on the network drive anymore.